# How to make svg paths clickable in leaflet and get path ID by clicking

Tags: javascript, css, svg, leaflet, kml

I am new to leaflet programming, I have a .svg file and I want to make that clickable on super imposing on open street map.

I have tried making it as an overlay on an open street map by `Image-overlay` option but svg is not clickable.

Basically I want to get the ID of clicked svg path or element (what ever you call) in leaflet. The map is getting zoom when I clicked.

```
var imageUrl = 'test2.svg', 
                imageBounds = [(image bounds)]; 
L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map);
```

Comment: share some code

Comment: var imageUrl = 'test2.svg',
        imageBounds = [(image bounds)];
      L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map);

Comment: I am just overlaying the svg as image i don't know this is correct approach. kindly suggest me if any other better way thank you

Comment: If you load an SVG as an image it's not going to be interactive i.e. you won't be able to access the ID of clicked path elements.

Comment: thank you Robert Longson, then could you please suggest the best way to do that ?

Comment: What happens when adding a `click` handler to the `L.ImageOverlay` instance?

Comment: Added code from OP's comment into the question - also fixed grammar.

Comment: Don't load the SVG as an image, do it some other way that doesn't impose image restrictions (assuming there is such a way).

Comment: hi IvanSanchez nothing happening after adding on click event to ImageOverlay thank you

Comment: hi  Robert Longson, i am trying other ways to get svg on leaflet. Meanwhile kindly suggest me if is there any other ways we can do that. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

**Loading the SVG file**

You can load your file through an `imageOverlay` but you won't get events on individual paths/groups/shapes, you are limited to events on the overlay.

To get events on the components of the SVG, you have to embed it into your DOM nodes, either by inlining it or by loading it and creating the required nodes. Something like this <sup>1</sup>:

```js
var url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fd/Ghostscript_Tiger.svg';
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onload = function(resp) {
    var xml = this.responseXML;
    var importedNode = document.importNode(xml.documentElement, true);
    var g = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g");
    g.appendChild(importedNode);
    g.setAttribute('class', 'svglayer');

    var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
    svg.appendChild(g);
    svg.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        console.log(e.target.id)
    })

    document.body.appendChild(svg);
};
req.open("GET", url, true);
req.send();
```

This snippet will load a SVG file, append it to the DOM et and setup a `click` event that will log the id of the target element.

**Embedding SVG into a map**

Armed with this knowledge, you can append the SVG node to a map pane instead of the `document.body`. Here's a simple example that directly modifies the `overlay` pane :

```
map.getPane('overlayPane').appendChild(svg);
```

An important point to note is that Leaflet disables clicking on individual path elements by setting the [CSS property `pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) to `none`. You have to alter this to get events on the path nodes, hence the added CSS property:

```
.leaflet-pane > svg .svglayer path {
    pointer-events: auto ;
}
```

And a demo

```js
var map = L.map(document.getElementById('map'),{
    renderer: L.canvas()
}).setView([48.8583736, 2.2922926], 15);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);


var url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fd/Ghostscript_Tiger.svg';
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onload = function(resp) {
    var xml = this.responseXML;
    var importedNode = document.importNode(xml.documentElement, true);
    var g = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g");
    g.appendChild(importedNode);
    g.setAttribute('class', 'svglayer');

    var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
    svg.appendChild(g);
    svg.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        console.log(e.target.id, e.target.tagName)
    })

    map.getPane('overlayPane').appendChild(svg);
};
req.open("GET", url, true);
req.send();
```

```css
html, body {padding:0; margin:0; height: 100%}
#map {height: 180px}


.leaflet-pane > svg .svglayer path {
    pointer-events: auto ;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-M2wvCLH6DSRazYeZRIm1JnYyh22purTM+FDB5CsyxtQJYeKq83arPe5wgbNmcFXGqiSH2XR8dT/fJISVA1r/zQ==" crossorigin=""/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-lInM/apFSqyy1o6s89K4iQUKg6ppXEgsVxT35HbzUupEVRh2Eu9Wdl4tHj7dZO0s1uvplcYGmt3498TtHq+log==" crossorigin=""></script>

<div id='map'>

</div>
```

<sup>1</sup> Image by Ghostscript authors (GPL Ghostscript SVN: tiger.eps) [GPL (http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html)], via [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3AGhostscript_Tiger.svg)

Comment: nice solution, but how to make svg scale with zoom??

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly specify the [`interactive`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#imageoverlay-interactive) option on your Image Overlay:

> If `true`, the image overlay will emit mouse events when clicked or hovered.

```js
var map = L.map("map").setView([48.85, 2.35], 12);

var imageBounds = [
  [48.8, 2.3],
  [48.9, 2.4]
];

var imageUrl = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9c/Map_of_country_subdivisions_%28states%29.svg';

var imageOverlay = L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds, {
  interactive: true,
  attribution: '<a href="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Map_of_country_subdivisions_(states).svg">CC-BY-SA 4.0 Wikimedia contributor</a>'
}).addTo(map);

imageOverlay.on('click', function(event) {
  alert('clicked on SVG image');
});

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>

<div id="map" style="height: 200px"></div>
```

Comment: awesome ghybs, thank you. looks cool but i want to get id of the g tag in svg file how to do that

Comment: Feel free to open a new question with an example of your code and sample data.